# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'book' django

Tags: python, django, django-models

First I create a new app **book** and create a model class `book`, then I messed up with that. I delete that app and create another app and run `python3 manage.py runserver`.

Then I get this error:
[image].

I don't add anything in the new app. What can I do now? Is there anything more I want to specify?

**project directory and installed apps**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dubcR.png)

Comment: Hi! Can we have a look at your project directory?

Comment: And have you imported your app into your ```settings.py``` correctly under ```INSTALLED_APPS```?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

after creating any app in django, you need to add it's name to the INSTALLED_APPS inside the settings.py file.

Also make sure to run makemigrations before running migrate command like below:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

for a specific app:

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app name>
```